# Esri ArcGIS server: Errors rendering annotation features

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, annotation

We have a ArcGIS Server 10 site based in Map Services that has some annotation feature classes. Most of the time the annotation text displays correctly. However, sometimes the rendering of annotation features 'goes crazy'.

![Bad Annotations][1]

Our annotation features are plain text, usually numerical or alphanumerical codes with 1 to 4 characters, using font Arial. When the rendering 'goes crazy' the annotations are rendering instead with:
•   A different font (ex. Wingdings), or
•   A different text angle, or
•   A different size, or
•   with underline or strikeout, or
•   with the characters overlapping each other's

These errors occur randomly and can affect all the features displayed from a feature class or not. The way each feature is displayed just keep changing as we zoom and pan. In attachment I'm sending two images that illustrates the phenomena.

Have you ever experienced the same problem? Do you have an idea what could be the source of the problem?

The client side of our site is developed with the Flex API 2.4. The Map Services are not cached as the data used is subject to updates every night. Our data is an ArcSDE 9.3.1 geodatabase, based on Oracle 10.

Your feedback will be welcome.

Regards,
Paula Lopes

Altran.com
Belgium